Why does the Carlyle circle method fail to produce a regular n-gon for non-prime Fermat numbers?
The Carlyle circle method readily produces a regular pentagon, 17-gon, 257-gon and it seems the 65537-gon
DeTemple, Duane W. (Feb 1991). "Carlyle circles and Lemoine simplicity of polygon constructions". The American Mathematical Monthly. 98 (2): 97–108. doi:10.2307/2323939.
But for non-prime Fermat numbers by Gauss's theorem this method does not produce a regular n-gon.  How/where does the apparently formalistic Carlyle circle method fail for non-prime Fermat numbers?
Does this have anything to do with there only being four normed division algebras?

The construction for an $n$-gon relies on $\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ being irreducible. For $n=2^3+1=9$, $\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}=(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$. It has nothing to do with the fact there are only 4 normed division algebras.

It is well known that a $n-gon$ is constructable with ruler and compass iff $\varphi(n)$ is a power of $2$. This is equivalent to : $n$ is a product of a power of $2$ and pairwise distinct fermat primes. If $2^{16}+1$ is the largest fermat prime (which is an open problem) , then this holds for only finite many odd $n$.
